# aurelia.js print a value in my DOM from a select

Tags: javascript, aurelia

my values are been printing in a alert, but how can I print this value in my DOM? like in a h1 tag?

app.html:

```
<template>

  <select value.bind="changedValue" change.delegate="DropdownChanged(changedValue)">
    <option model.bind="1">1</option>
    <option model.bind="2">2</option>
    <option model.bind="3">3</option>
    <option model.bind="4">4</option>
  </select>

</template>
```

app.js

```
export class App {
  changedValue;


  DropdownChanged(changedVal) {
    alert(changedVal);
  }

}
```

https://gist.run/?id=87f6897928feb504dad638d439caf92f

Comment: how about `<h1>${changedValue}</h1> ` in your template and `this.changedValue = changedVal` in your change function delegate?

Comment: The change handler is completely unnecessary. That's what Aurelia's databinding system does for you. Just get rid of the change handler and bind directly to the property that is bound to the value of the dropdown. https://gist.run/?id=f5d953abebb7f323d88b05e80cb04b00

Comment: If you need to run code when the value changes, you can simply call the function, but don't need to set the property value in it. https://gist.run/?id=8e5f28a2f88d6c248880aafe3ef0df95

Answer (score 0):

Your `changedValue` in App holds the model you select as I see it.

You just need to give it a default (and maybe a better name)

```
export class App {
  value = 1;
```

Then update it when a different value is selected instead of alerting.

```
DropdownChanged(changedVal) {
  this.value = changedVal;
}
```

Then you can freely use it in your template

```
<template>
    <h1>${value}</h1>
...
```

As suggested, you might not need the change interceptor at all, in which case you can just bind to the select's model:

```
<select value.bind="selectedValue">
```

and

```
<h1>Selected Value: ${selectedValue}</h1>
```

(no need for any js code in this particular simplified example)

Comment: I'd recommend you look at the two gists I linked to above and update your answer :-)

Comment: Makes sense but I didn't want to make any assumptions about OP use case - it might have been that intercepting the change is needed for something else.